# Ignore a specific character when opening a file in python / csv

Tags: python, csv, encoding

I wrote a python script to output lines and cells of a csv file.
The file I read has been exported from the address-book of a shipment company utility.
It appears, that this file is somehow "corrupted". The co-workers who registered the addresses did some wrong copy-paste and inserted many quotation marks often without closing them. And this messes up the csv-file which looks approx. like this when I read it with *less* or *cat*: (I numbered the lines)

```
1 ;name1;address1;"phone number1;;
2 ;name2;address2;phone number2;;
3 ;name3;address3;"phone number3;;
```

The contents of 'line 1, cell 4' until 'line 3, cell 3;' end up in the line 1 cell 4 altogether... when I output it with my script I see:

```
1 ;name1;address1;phone number1;;;name2;address2;phone number2;;;name3;address3;
2 phone number3;;
```

The thing is, my file is 30000 lines long and this mistake is repeated over hundreds of lines.

The solution is obvious: replace all quotation marks with nothing.

The question is: what is the best solution to let python read the file correctly?
Or: Is there a way to open the file in python and make the script **ignore** the quotation marks? which would be very nice, I think.
Should I find/replace with python first? 
Should I correct the encoding/re-encode the file?
I've no idea how the file is encoded:

```
$ file -i myfile.csv
myfile.csv: text/plain; charset=unknown-8bit
```

--

Here is the code of my script in case it would help. Please don't mind the unpythonicnesses. This only is the second script I ever wrote...

```
import sys, csv

file = sys.argv[1]
x = int(sys.argv[2]) - 1
if len  (sys.argv) == 4:
    y = int(sys.argv[3]) - 1

f = open(file, 'rb') 
cr = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')

lst = []
linecount = 0

for row in cr:
    lst.append(row)
    linecount += 1

if 'y' in locals():
    line = lst[x][y]
    print line
    print '-'*len(line), '\n', 'line number', x + 1, '|', 'cell number', y + 1
    print len(lst[x]), 'cells'

else:
    print lst[x]

print '\n', file, linecount, 'lines'
```

*I maybe should use csv.next() instead of putting everything in a list.*

Comment: Why don't you just send this file back to whoever is responsible for this mess asking them politely but very firmly to deliver a __proper__ csv file ?

Comment: because it costs money...

Comment: If you had to pay for it, they should definitly deliver a usable product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) , it has the option to set quotechar and here you can set the value to None.

```
cr = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';',quotechar=None)
```

Comment: So nice ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

not a real answer (i lack the rep to comment, but i edit this for a real answer later.)

if you have linux or cygwin available try: `sed 's/"//' filename`